# Confliction between joomla module and joomla plugin

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

Hai I am using two extensions in the same article page of a joomla article,

1.Module-->image crawler for slideshow
2.plugin-->dynamic chart for content display.

The problem here is If I unpublished the either one among these two working fine but Both together cannot.

Please get me solution for this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide a link to your site? Do they both use jQuery? Can you provide some code for the jQuery being imported by both extensions? Are you getting any errors in the console? please provide more detail

Comment: var jq = jQuery.noConflict();OFC.jQuery ={name : "jQuery",version : function(src) {return jq('#' + src)[0].get_version();},rasterize : function(src, dst){jq('#'+dst).replaceWith(OFC.jQuery.image(src));},
image : function(src){return "<img src='data:image/png;base64,"+jq('#' + src)[0].get_img_binary() + "' />";},popup : function(src) {var img_win = window.open('', 'Charts: Export as Image');with (img_win.document) {write('<html><head><title>Charts: Export as Image<\/title><\/head><body>'+OFC.jQuery.image(src) + '<\/body><\/html>');}// stop the 'loading...' message img_win.document.close();}};

Comment: Hai Lodder,Thank you to your replay...

Answer (score 0):

You've got a javascript conflict, I would guess that both extensions are loading a different version of jQuery. Instal jQuery Easy to remove the extra versions and that should fix your issue.